# PHP + PDF, how to save a downloaded PDF using curl?

Tags: php, pdf, curl, header, save

Welcome

I have a little problem with saving the downloaded pdf on the page. To download pdf I use Curl:

```
$CurlConnect = curl_init();
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://website.com/invoices/download/1');
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POST,   1);
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login.':'.$password);
$Result = curl_exec($CurlConnect);
```

Now in **$Result**(string) i have all PDF file content. And now begins my problem. I would like to save the downloaded pdf:

```
header('Cache-Control: public'); 
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="new.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($Result));
readfile($Result);
```

Unfortunately, when I save or open a new PDF file, I get a blank document. Perhaps the problem is with the last lines of:

```
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($Result));
readfile($Result);
```

Unfortunately, I do not know what to change them to make it work ... I ask for your help. Thanks

Comment: why dont you use http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-save.php

Comment: I think there is some error occuring in your code. Wrap your code in a try-catch block and add some debugging steps.

Comment: I didn't test but I think that for `filesize()` and `readfile()` you need a real file's path instead of it's content as string.

Comment: also try with http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both [filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) and [readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) accepts files as arguments. You are providing a string instead of a file.

Please try this.

```
$CurlConnect = curl_init();
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://website.com/invoices/download/1');
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POST,   1);
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login.':'.$password);
$Result = curl_exec($CurlConnect);

header('Cache-Control: public'); 
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="new.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($Result));
echo $Result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that:

```
// ...
$Result = curl_exec($CurlConnect);
$file = 'file.pdf';
$fileName = 'fileName.pdf';
file_put_contents($file, $Result);
```

and than:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

readfile($file);
```

I hope I helped!