# Trying to download PDF via cURL, getting 404 - but browser works (206 partial-content)

Tags: php, pdf, curl

I haven't been able to configure cURL to download a PDF from a particular remote server.  I installed LiveHTTTPHeaders in order to get a better picture of what's happening. The following output is from the successful transfer through a browser. Is there a way to do the same thing through cURL, without knowing prior the byte ranges, etc.  Or is it impossible?

LiveHTTPHeaders Output for successful transfer through browser:

```
https://www.unitedhealthcareonline.com/ccmcontent/ProviderII/UHC/en-US/Assets/ProviderStaticFiles/ProviderStaticFilesPdf/Tools%20and%20Resources/Policies%20and%20Protocols/Medical%20Policies/Medical%20Policies/Ablative_Treatment_for_Spinal_Pain.pdf

GET /ccmcontent/ProviderII/UHC/en-US/Assets/ProviderStaticFiles/ProviderStaticFilesPdf/Tools%20and%20Resources/Policies%20and%20Protocols/Medical%20Policies/Medical%20Policies/Ablative_Treatment_for_Spinal_Pain.pdf HTTP/1.1
Host: www.unitedhealthcareonline.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://www.unitedhealthcareonline.com/b2c/CmaAction.do?channelId=016228193392b010VgnVCM100000c520720a____
Connection: keep-alive
Range: bytes=112744-
If-Range: "ec675-272e0-4fa9e598c8240"
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 25 Aug 2014 18:11:58 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 30 May 2014 13:52:01 GMT
Etag: "cc675-272e0-4fa9e598c8240"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 160480
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=1000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/pdf
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerwww.unitedhealthcareonline.com_8080=1749579530.36895.0000; expires=Mon, 25-Aug-2014 18:41:58 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: TSebd2a0=2004f3a590c6498a85ac153996f42ede70886359fd2aa60453fb7c6ee6ddab836091fb4f; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly
----------------------------------------------------------
https://www.unitedhealthcareonline.com/ccmcontent/ProviderII/UHC/en-US/Assets/ProviderStaticFiles/ProviderStaticFilesPdf/Tools%20and%20Resources/Policies%20and%20Protocols/Medical%20Policies/Medical%20Policies/Ablative_Treatment_for_Spinal_Pain.pdf

GET /ccmcontent/ProviderII/UHC/en-US/Assets/ProviderStaticFiles/ProviderStaticFilesPdf/Tools%20and%20Resources/Policies%20and%20Protocols/Medical%20Policies/Medical%20Policies/Ablative_Treatment_for_Spinal_Pain.pdf HTTP/1.1
Host: www.unitedhealthcareonline.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://www.unitedhealthcareonline.com/b2c/CmaAction.do?channelId=016228193392b010VgnVCM100000c520720a____
Connection: keep-alive
If-Range: "ec675-272e0-4fa9e598c8240"
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Range: bytes=131072-160479
Cookie: BIGipServerwww.unitedhealthcareonline.com_8080=1749579530.36895.0000; TSebd2a0=2004f3a590c6498a85ac153996f42ede70886359fd2aa60453fb7c6ee6ddab836091fb4f

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 25 Aug 2014 18:11:59 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 30 May 2014 13:52:01 GMT
Etag: "cc675-272e0-4fa9e598c8240"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 160480
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=1000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/pdf
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerwww.unitedhealthcareonline.com_8080=1749579530.36895.0000; expires=Mon, 25-Aug-2014 18:41:59 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: TSebd2a0=2004f3a590c6498a85ac153996f42ede70886359fd2aa60453fb7c6ee6ddab836091fb4f; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly
----------------------------------------------------------
```

cURL configuration:

```
$cookie_file = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "tmp" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . explode('/', $url )[2] . '.txt';

        strpos( $url, 'https' ) !== false ? $secure_connection = true : $secure_connection = false;


        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0' );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true );
        if( $secure_connection == true )
        {
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1); 
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, SERVER_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cacert.pem' );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true );
        }
        if( isset($this->referer) && $this->referer != null ) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->referer);

        $errors = curl_error( $ch );
        $content = curl_exec( $ch );

        $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
```

Comment: I know that curl can be a sort of pain in the ass, have you tried using file_get_contents()?  Perhaps the SSL is causing the issue.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897264/php-pdf-how-to-save-a-downloaded-pdf-using-curl

Comment: I have tried file_get_contents, same deal.

Comment: I have gone through that solution as well, to no avail. It's the same issue.

Comment: I have been basically googling this for days and have tried so many suggestions that my head is spinning.  I'm probably going to end up putting a bounty on this, when it's available in two days.

Comment: curl has a verbose setting you can use via the command line, which should give some info as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Thankyou!! I literally just started using that, good timing.

Comment: I just tried curl -o <SAVE-TO> <THE-URL> from the command line and it worked no problem.  How do I mimic this in PHP?

Comment: WOW, I solved it.  It was spaces in the URL. WTF?!?!!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that i have some more simple way to do that without cURL.
Use PHP readfile with suitable headers like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile("https://www.unitedhealthcareonline.com/ccmcontent/ProviderII/UHC/en-US/Assets/ProviderStaticFiles/ProviderStaticFilesPdf/Tools%20and%20Resources/Policies%20and%20Protocols/Medical%20Policies/Medical%20Policies/Ablative_Treatment_for_Spinal_Pain.pdf");
?>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm accepting yours because I already answered my own question.